# Mongorestore --gzip --archive failed w/ - 0 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

after many hours scouring the internet (including here on Stackoverflow), checking the documentation back and forth of the official MongoDB website. I still did not find the solution why my archived file with mongodump is not restored with the following commands

`mongorestore --gzip --drop --nsInclude="*" --archive=/./././code/backups/notura-db-1659281356578.gzip -v`

I get the following output:

```
2022-07-31T23:55:19.574+0200    using write concern: &{majority false 0}
2022-07-31T23:55:19.606+0200    will listen for SIGTERM, SIGINT, and SIGKILL
2022-07-31T23:55:19.607+0200    connected to node type: standalone
2022-07-31T23:55:19.619+0200    archive format version "0.1"
2022-07-31T23:55:19.619+0200    archive server version "5.0.3"
2022-07-31T23:55:19.619+0200    archive tool version "100.5.1"
2022-07-31T23:55:19.620+0200    preparing collections to restore from
2022-07-31T23:55:19.632+0200    demux finishing (err:<nil>)
2022-07-31T23:55:19.632+0200    received  from namespaceChan
2022-07-31T23:55:19.632+0200    restoring up to 4 collections in parallel
2022-07-31T23:55:19.632+0200    building indexes up to 4 collections in parallel
2022-07-31T23:55:19.632+0200    0 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

I do not get any error message, nor does my database getting updated.

I am running MongoDB 5.0.3 Community

Any help is highly appreciated!

Aron

Comment: What happens if you ask `mongorestore`/MongoDB to do "less", e.g., `mongorestore --noIndexRestore --noOptionsRestore --bypassDocumentValidation ...`?

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately the outcome is exactly the same. I get the same message, saying: 0 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.

Comment: What happens if you do **not** use `--nsInclude="*"`?  I.e., do not use `--nsInclude` at all.

Comment: Thanks for your help, meanwhile I found the solution. I meshed up with the name of the database. There was zero data in the archive file, which I didn't know. You made some valid points though! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, you can see my discussion over this here:

https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongorestore-gzip-archive-failed-w-0-document-s-restored-successfully-0-document-s-failed/178114/5

It is important to know if the database name is indeed correct. If you do not specify any in MongoDB shell (enter with mongosh, mongod or mongo) --> use your-db-name, with show dbs (in the mongodb shell) you will see which databases there are. Create one or use the standard one which is test.

The write the following to dump your database:
`mongodump --uri="mongodb://localhost:27017"  --db="your-database-name" --gzip --archive=/code/backups/notura-db.gz`

In the backups folder notura-db.gz file will be created. You can see if everything works correctly by doing mongoexport / mongoimport before you go to the more sophisticated method.

To restore the data, use the following command-line command:
`mongorestore --drop --gzip --nsInclude="*" --archive=/code/backups/notura-db.gz -v`

Cheers!

Aron